# How can I dump all content of an hdf5 file into an R list using hdf5r (and not rhdf5)

Tags: r, matlab, hdf5

I have several `.mat` files (saved as `-v7.3` which is HDF5 compliant) which I want to import as R objects in R. I tried `rhdf5::h5dump()` and it works great, with the exception that the H5 class `REFERENCE` is not supported. Some of the files have data stored as `REFERENCE` (as far as I can tell, MATLAB `cell`s are saved as `REFERENCE`s in the HDF5 `.mat` file).

hdf5r instead supports `REFERENCE` objects. Is there a corresponding function in hdf5r that does what `rhdf5::h5dump()` does? Or alternatively, what would be the best way to recursively read the content of each file?